# C# Selenium Use Proxy with Username and Password

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--proxy-server=" + proxy);
```

How can I print on this alert?

Comment: How will the proxy get around the password prompt?

Comment: Username and password defined in a variable

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense. The `proxy` variable contains the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
SendKeys.Send(user);
SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
SendKeys.Send(pass);
SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?